# Adding a list using AlertDialog API

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

After reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html, I would like to create an alert dialog as depicted below:

[image]

Basically, I would like to have an alert dialog with a title and four options as an activity (i.e. ColorAlertDialog.class).

Can someone please explain how this can be achieved.

Comment: Have you tried coding what's in the documentation you are referring to? Which part of the documentation don't you understand?

Comment: Can you explain the .setItems method, this is where I am confused. I would like to know what R.array.pick_color is exactly?

Comment: ok this refers to the XML file /res/values/arrays.xml that you need to create. You then edit this file and put your array values in there. An example of an integer array is here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use adapter and adb.setadapter() method. Adb will automatically use native Android list. Benefit of this approach is that Android takes care about  your dialogs styles on every Android version. 
Some samples of code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    String[] from = { ObjectViewContract.Columns.LABORCODE };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, null, from, to, 0);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSherlockActivity());
    adb.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_title_objectfilter));
    adb.setAdapter(mAdapter, this);
    return adb.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You just need to create a custom view (e.g.: R.layout.group_simple_alertdialog) such as on your picture and add this to your `AlertDialog.Builder`.
2. After that you also have to `setOnItemClickListener` in the way to get the selected color from the view back

e.g.:

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
  View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_simple_alertdialog, null, false);
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setView(customView);
  builder.setCancelable(false);

  ListView list= (ListView) customView.findById(R.id.listView);
  // set now setOnItemClickListener and so on
```